# PostgreSQL differences in value 1 and 11

Tags: sql, postgresql

I try to call to my DB and where is only one table:

```
id | value
----------
 1 | 1|2|4
 2 | 11|23
 3 | 1|4|3|11
 4 | 2|4|11
 5 | 5|6|11
 6 | 12|15|16
 7 | 3|1|4
 8 | 5|2|1
```

QUERY was : `SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE value LIKE '%1%'`

I want to select only rows with value 1 but I get rows with 11 value to.

How to show in SQL differences?

Comment: Don't store separated values in a single column. It's bad design and will give you a lot of trouble in the long run.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have to stick with this broken design, it's probably better to use Postgres' ability to parse a string into an array.

This is more robust than using a `like` condition:

```
select *
from the_table
where string_to_array(value,'|') @> array['1']
```

or maybe a bit easier to read

```
select *
from the_table
where '1' = any (string_to_array(value,'|'))
```

using the overlaps operator `@>` you can also search for more than one value at a time:

```
select *
from the_table
where string_to_array(value,'|') @> array['1','2']
```

will return all rows where `value` contains `1` **and** `2`

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/8793d/2

Comment: regular expressions not needed, `string_to_array(value, '|')` could do the work.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend that you should normalize your schema to every column store only [atomic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) values.

Without it, you are forced to do some nasty trick, f.ex. with [arrays](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html):

```
select * from t
where '1' = any (string_to_array(value, '|'))
```

or, with [pattern matching](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html):

```
select * from t
where '1' similar to value
```

[<kbd>SQLFiddle</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a0b0f/8)